# Advantages of implementing a navbar.html in django templates?

Tags: django

I want to develop a best practice for placing a navbar in all my Django web apps.

At the moment I am placing the navbar in base.html. And then extending base.html on all other templates.

I have seen that some people create a navbar.html and then include that in base.html.

Is there a best practice here? Are there any advantages to using navbar.html?

Comment: I usually have my navbar in the `base.html`. Extracting navbar to a separate file would make sense if you wanted to reuse it in the future, or if your `base.html` gets overloaded with other stuff(try to avoid it). After all the choice is yours.

Comment: Well, It depends, there is nothing best. I do the second way. Just because it gives more flexibility and less html at one place.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some peoples are like to decouple each of components/section. For example, some people want to separate `footer.html`, `sidebar.html`, `navbar.html`, `topbar.html`, `rightbar.html` etc and include it on `base.html`. This it does not give you any extra advantages rather than some thinks if I just want to change something in my `footer`, then I just go to my `footer.html` and change what I want. By this I don't need to go `base.html` and scroll down to find were is my `footer` section.